# php graph api access token expires

Tags: php, curl, facebook-graph-api

I get my facebook feed via php curl like this:

```
$accessToken = "MYTOKEN";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/me/feed?'.http_build_query(
    array(
            "limit"                     =>  "3",
            "fields"                    =>  "attachments,created_time",
            "access_token"      =>  $accessToken
    )));


$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
curl_close($ch);
```

This works, but after a while I get this error:

```
[error] => Array
    (
        [message] => Error validating access token: Session has expired on Tuesday, 24-Aug-21 06:00:00 PDT. The current time is Tuesday, 24-Aug-21 06:02:33 PDT.
        [type] => OAuthException
        [code] => 190
        [error_subcode] => 463
        [fbtrace_id] => xyz
    )
```

Have I renew the token every time or generate every time a new one?
If yes, how??

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing

Comment: Hi ! meanwhile I have now a access token, but a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917474/get-facebook-page-posts