# get facebook page posts

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I found this article which explains how I can get access to my facebook page feed:
https://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/1170/embed-facebook-page-feed-on-my-website

What I have now:

- Access Token

And a php curl command with the url of the article above:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_NAME/posts?'.http_build_query(
    array(
            "limit"                     =>  "3",
            "fields"                    =>  "full_picture,picture,link,message,created_time",
            "access_token"      =>  "MY_APP_ID|MY_APP_SECRET"
    )));
    

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
curl_close($ch);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

But the results looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => (#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 10
            [fbtrace_id] => xyz
        )

)
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The error refers to some articles which give some help - what do they say about the message?

Comment: for me unclear. Always is the information "facebook login". But why I need a login?? I  only would like to embedded my page feed on my website (without the facebook plugin). And therefore should no Facebook login necessary, isn't it?

Comment: You can not use your app token for this, you need to use a user token of a page admin, or a page token.

Comment: what's the difference ? which von would be best practice and how I get those tokens?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: maybe I see the part in the documentation not, but I found this to get an page access token `curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}`. But for this request I need the user-access-token: How can I get this ??

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: yes but this is the problem which I don't understand: Why need I a login for this? Is it correct, that each visitor of my website have to login via facebook before seeing my page feed ???

Comment: Why you need a login - because Facebook decided so. And no, of course you don't ask your site visitor to log in - _they_ could not grant `pages_read_engagement` so that it applies to _your_ page in the first place (meaning, you would have to have the Page Public Content Access approved for your app, otherwise it would not work anyway.) You have your page access token stored on the server side, so you just use that to make the API request.